# How to do horizantal sub menu

Tags: html, css

Before my english a little. So I am sorry.

I try a dropown menu with css. When completed the menu, as below image final view.

[image]

Sub menu list must be side by side.

But my problem. My list are not happening side-by-side in sub-menu class.

**EDIT**
If I write a constant width for #dl_menu .sub-menu everything is ok. But my .sub-menu maybe possible 3 item, maybe 6 item and my sub-menu is width change it. isnt' it. ?
So I can't write constant width.

Example as this link.

http://jsbin.com/fulekulo/7/edit?html,css,output

Thank you for help.
Thank you.

Comment: Remove `position:relative` from `#dl_menu li`

Answer (score 0):

```
#dl_menu .sub-menu{width:400px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/dsx8R/

Comment: because you sub-menu is display:table... so width: you custom

Comment: First Thanx your help. I edit my problem. Do you look again please. ?

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Menu CSS Like This

```
#dl_menu .sub-menu {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 304px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: First Thanx your help @Sid. I edit my problem. Do you look again please. ?

Comment: Your parent Ul not have that much width so in these case you need to Set width dynamically using JQuery Like If First Click then $("#dl_menu .sub-menu").width('300px') and when second menu click $("#dl_menu .sub-menu").width('400px') and so on.